# QApplication is not running in main thread when building PySide app bundle with py2app

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyside, py2app

I am having problems building my PySide Python app using py2app (for OS X). It appears that something funny happens with threads on the app bundle.

Here is the minimal example

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        QApplication.__init__(self, sys.argv, True)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = App()
    app.exec_()
```

When run from the command line: `python test.py`, this works fine without error. However when I then compile it with the following setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
import py2app
import PySide

APP = ['test.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': False,
            'includes' : 'PySide',
            'resources' : "qt_menu.nib"
            }

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

these errors appear in the Console:

```
11/05/2013 13:54:20.958 [0x0-0xb37b37].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
11/05/2013 13:54:20.958 [0x0-0xb37b37].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test: (Parent is App(0x105f41f10), parent's thread is QThread(0x100106cc0), current thread is QThread(0x10251ea80)
```

So it appears that App is not being constructed to live in the main thread any more. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't reproduce your issue using PyQt4 (Qt-4.8.3, PyQt-4.9.5, OSX-10.7, Python-2.7.3, py2app-0.7.3).  Perhaps this issue only affects PySide users?

Comment: That's odd. Py2app doesn't create threads in the application bundle.

Comment: BTW. You don't have to import Pyside in your setup.py file.

Comment: Thanks - it is strange. It might also be worth mentioning that I'm using MacPorts. I have a hunch that the issue may involve a dependency that has installed itself for both Python 3 and Python 2, although there's not much in the error messages to support that.

Comment: Yep, compiling on a friend's MacPorts setup doesn't have this problem - there must be something funny with my setup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the way PySide manage the QThreads. Yo're creating a `QTimer` with a `QApplication` as parent. When using `PyQt4` that's not as problem, but it might be on PySide.

A `QTimer` also spawns a `QThread` so, try run your code without creating the `QTimer`.

Note: At the time you asked the question, this could be a bug. And might be fixed in the last versions of PySide. (I'm just speculating :D)